# Exception while trying to run eclipse product

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I got the below exception while trying to run an eclipse product which exported without errors

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.<init>
```

any clue?

Full stack trace:

```
!SESSION 2013-07-23 02:08:52.676 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-07-23 02:08:54.202
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.<init>(ModelServiceImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at myapp.MyApp.start(MyApp.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: can u paste the full stacktrace ?

Comment: @saurav updated with full trace. Thanks!

Comment: This link should help http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/275845/

Comment: @saurav I saw this, but does this really help? Have you seen this issue yourself? How did you troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating my Eclipse 3.7 application to 4.3. The solution was to replace the contents of the  tag in my product file with the following:

```
<configurations>
   <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
   <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" autoStart="true" startLevel="3" />
   <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="3" />
</configurations>
```

Also see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/FAQ#Why_won.27t_my_application_start.3F

Comment: Where is the "product file" located, what is its exact name?

Comment: Usually in the root directory of your project. If you dont have such a file, you have to create a product first (CTRL + N -> Product Configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing spaces in your debug configuration names.

I'm pretty reluctant to write this here as I know it sounds crazy and I have no proof/explanation whatsoever. But here is my story.
I was translating my eclipse java application (RCP) and had 2 debug launch configurations. One to launch in Dutch and 1 to launch in English.
All of a sudden these stopped working with the stack trace like above.
I started undoing changes, but to no avail.
Internet search lead me here but the changes proposed by the accepted answer didn't help my case.
Then I created a new launch configuration by clicking the debug icon in the product manifest.
That one worked. Checking the differences in the launch configuration files showed no differences except for the config name and location.
Being a C/C++ guy I removed the spaces in the config name in the gui and bang it started working again :-s
The weird thing is that both configs contained spaces and by removing the spaces in one of them, they both started working. 
As it took me way over 4 hours to fix this I thought I'd share this.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit your `congif.ini`

before:

> osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start

after:

> osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.equinox.ds@2:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start