# After migrating sources from Indigo to Kepler,product is not launching

Tags: eclipse, rcp, eclipse-kepler

I've migrated my rcp application from Indigo to Kepler with no source changes.After successful export the product is not launching.It is throwing the error,

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-05-20 16:18:57.384
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.<init>(ModelServiceImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
```

I've already tried the solution given in the link,
[Exception while trying to run eclipse product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802661/exception-while-trying-to-run-eclipse-product)

but still the same error I'm getting.

Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your product, do you use an existing config.ini file ? or do you generate a default ?

Comment: Why Eclipse Kepler (4.3)? Eclipse Luna (4.4.2) is current with Eclipse Mars (4.5) due for release in June.

Comment: I'm using existing config.ini file.I didn't generate any default ini file.

Comment: I generated default config.ini file and customized my product settings.Now I'm able to launch it successfully.Thanks for your help!